# Boost beast::websocket callback functions

Tags: c++, boost, websocket

I am experimenting with the Boost beast::websocket [websocket_client_async.cpp](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/beast/example/websocket/client/async/websocket_client_async.cpp) example, in conjunction with [websocket_server_async.cpp](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/beast/example/websocket/server/async/websocket_server_async.cpp).

As given, the *client* example just makes a connection, sends a string to the server (which simply echoes back), prints the reply, closes, and exists.

I'm trying to modify the client to keep the session alive, so that I can repeatedly send/receive strings. So, whereas the example code's `on_handshake` function immediately sends the string via `ws_.async_write(...)`, I separate that out into its own `write(...)` function.

Here is my modified `session` class:

```
using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;
namespace websocket = boost::beast::websocket;

void fail(boost::system::error_code ec, char const* what)
{
    std::cerr << what << ": " << ec.message() << "\n";
}

// Sends a WebSocket message and prints the response
class session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<session>
{
    tcp::resolver resolver_;
    websocket::stream<tcp::socket> ws_;
    std::atomic<bool> io_in_progress_;
    boost::beast::multi_buffer buffer_;
    std::string host_;

public:
    // Resolver and socket require an io_context
    explicit session(boost::asio::io_context& ioc) : resolver_(ioc), ws_(ioc) {
        io_in_progress_ = false;
    }

    bool io_in_progress() const {
        return io_in_progress_;
    }

    // +---------------------+
    // | The "open" sequence |
    // +---------------------+
    void open(char const* host, char const* port)
    {
        host_ = host;

        // Look up the domain name
        resolver_.async_resolve(host, port,
            std::bind( &session::on_resolve, shared_from_this(),
                std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2 )
        );
    }

    void on_resolve(boost::system::error_code ec, tcp::resolver::results_type results)
    {
        if (ec)
            return fail(ec, "resolve");

        boost::asio::async_connect(
            ws_.next_layer(), results.begin(), results.end(),
            std::bind( &session::on_connect, shared_from_this(),
                std::placeholders::_1 )
        );
    }

    void on_connect(boost::system::error_code ec)
    {
        if (ec)
            return fail(ec, "connect");

        ws_.async_handshake(host_, "/",
            std::bind( &session::on_handshake, shared_from_this(),
                std::placeholders::_1 )
        );
    }

    void on_handshake(boost::system::error_code ec)
    {
        if (ec)
            return fail(ec, "handshake");
        else {
            std::cout << "Successful handshake with server.\n";
        }
    }

    // +---------------------------+
    // | The "write/read" sequence |
    // +---------------------------+
    void write(const std::string &text)
    {
        io_in_progress_ = true;
        ws_.async_write(boost::asio::buffer(text),
            std::bind( &session::on_write, shared_from_this(),
                std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2 )
        );
    }

    void on_write(boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
    {
        boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);
        if (ec)
            return fail(ec, "write");

        ws_.async_read(buffer_,
            std::bind( &session::on_read, shared_from_this(),
                std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2 )
        );
    }

    void on_read(boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
    {
        io_in_progress_ = false; // end of write/read sequence
        boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);
        if (ec)
            return fail(ec, "read");

        std::cout << boost::beast::buffers(buffer_.data()) << std::endl;
    }

    // +----------------------+
    // | The "close" sequence |
    // +----------------------+
    void close()
    {
        io_in_progress_ = true;
        ws_.async_close(websocket::close_code::normal,
            std::bind( &session::on_close, shared_from_this(),
                std::placeholders::_1)
        );
    }

    void on_close(boost::system::error_code ec)
    {
        io_in_progress_ = false; // end of close sequence
        if (ec)
            return fail(ec, "close");

        std::cout << "Socket closed successfully.\n";
    }
};
```

The problem is that, while the connection works fine and I can send a string, the `on_read` callback is never hit (unless I do an ugly hack described below).

My `main` looks like this:

```
void wait_for_io(std::shared_ptr<session> psession, boost::asio::io_context &ioc)
{
    // Continually try to run the ioc until the callbacks are finally
    // triggered (as indicated by the session::io_in_progress_ flag)
    while (psession->io_in_progress()) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
        ioc.run();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Check command line arguments.
    if (argc != 3) {
        std::cerr << "usage info goes here...\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    const char *host = argv[1], *port = argv[2];

    boost::asio::io_context ioc;
    std::shared_ptr<session> p = std::make_shared<session>(ioc);
    p->open(host, port);
    ioc.run(); // This works. Connection is established and all callbacks are executed.

    p->write("Hello world"); // String is sent & received by server,
                             // even before calling ioc.run()
                             // However, session::on_read callback is never
                             // reached.

    ioc.run();               // This seems to be ignored and returns immediately, so
    wait_for_io(p, ioc);     // <-- so this hack is necessary

    p->close();              // session::on_close is never reached
    ioc.run();               // Again, this seems to be ignored and returns immediately, so
    wait_for_io(p, ioc);     // <-- this is necessary

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If I do this:

```
p->write("Hello world");
while(1) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
}
```

I can confirm that the string is sent & received<sup>1</sup> by the server, and that the `session::on_read` callback is *not* reached.

Same thing occurs with `p->close()`.

But, if I add my weird `wait_for_io()` function, everything works. I'm positive this a terrible hack, but I can't figure out what's going on.

<sup>1</sup> Note: I can confirm that the message does reach the server, as I modified the server example to print any received strings to the console. This was the only modified I made. The echo-to-client functionality was not changed.

Comment: Just an observation, this code has undefined behavior. You are calling `boost::asio::buffer(text)` in `write`. But `text` can go out of scope while the asynchronous operation is still running. It is the caller's responsibility to ensure that the lifetime of memory buffers passed to stream algorithms remain valid at least until the corresponding completion handler is called.

Comment: @VinnieFalco Oops... good point. That was just a stupid transcription error I made while formatting my code for SO.SE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason the calls to `io_context::run()` are not working after the first call (shown here):

```
boost::asio::io_context ioc;
std::shared_ptr<session> p = std::make_shared<session>(ioc);
p->open(host, port);
ioc.run(); // This works. Connection is established and all callbacks are executed.
```

is because the function `io_context::restart()` must be called prior to any subsequent calls of `io_context::run`.

[From the documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context/restart.html):

> **io_context::restart**
>   Restart the *io_context* in preparation for a subsequent run() invocation.
> This function must be called prior to any second or later set of invocations of the run(), run_one(), poll() or poll_one() functions when a previous invocation of these functions returned due to the io_context being stopped or running out of work. After a call to restart(), the io_context object's stopped() function will return false.

Comment: gah...every single time it seems I forget about the need to call `restart`.

Answer (score 3):

`io_context::run` will only return when there is no more pending work. If you simply make sure that there is a pending call to `websocket::stream::async_read` active at all times, then `run` will never return and the hacks will not be needed. Also, you will receive all messages sent by the server.

Comment: Thanks Vinnie. I do understand that, and tested it that way to begin with, but had some difficulty ending the pending call cleanly, when I wanted to close the socket. But, to be honest I don't see how my code above doesn't adhere to to what you wrote in your first sentence. When I call p->write(...); just before ioc.run(); there IS pending work. And the read should then follow.

Comment: To clarify, when I call p->write(...), the function itself creates work - which is why I don't understand how ioc.run() fails to do anything.

Comment: If you want to close the websocket connection, just call `async_close`. Make sure you do that from the same implicit or explicit strand which is used to make the other calls. Pending calls to `async_read` and `async_write` will eventually completion with `websocket::error::closed` and `boost::asio::operation_aborted` respectively when the `async_close` operation has completed. I'm not sure exactly why `io_context::run` is returning right away, but it can only be because there is no pending work.

Comment: Yes, calling `async_close` does work - I'm not sure what the issue was that I had before; it's simple to do. Maybe I forgot to join the thread or something stupid. But it's a bit beside the point. My question is really regarding why the code above doesn't work. For now, I'm just testing my understanding of the library to be sure I have a firm grasp writing my operational code. I'd like to clear up this mystery before continuing. I'm beginning to think it's a bug in the library.

Comment: I would be very surprised if there was a defect in the latest release of Beast. The code almost has 100% coverage via tests, and the tests are quite exhaustive. The example clients and servers work as written. If they stop working, it is certainly because of any changes that were made. I would start over using the original code and verify that it does work as expected, and then apply your changes incrementally to find out what causes it to malfunction.

Comment: Thanks Vinnie. I was using 1.66, and it looks like they did iron out some bugs in 1.67. Still, it wasn't a bug. I figured it out. +1 for the help - I appreciate it.